# gdb continue after attach

Tags: c, gdb

I am debugging a program with multiple processes using GDB. There are two different processes involved all launched by the main program. Lets call them p1 (the process that is started on and eventually launches p2) p2 (the process that is launched and I want to attach to)

The trick is that I need to attach to p2 and break at a point in its process ONLY after a break point in p1.

So essentially I find myself doing:

```
gdb p1
(gdb) break foo
(gdb) attach <pid of p2>
(gdb) break bar
```

Where pid is determined by running a `ps` command in another tab while p1 is broken.

The problem with this is that when I attach to p2 p1 is still broken. Really the continue, attach, and new breakpoints need to all be done simultaniously. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two terminals: 1 and 2.

Do the following steps:

1. In Terminal 1, `gdb p1`. `break foo`.
2. In Terminal 1, `run`.
3. The break point will be hit in p1 and p1 will pause.
4. Now the process p2 would be running (since p1 has started running).
5. In the terminal 2. open gdb and attach p2. Add breakpoint in p2.
6. `continue` in terminal 1. And change to terminal 2.
7. You will see that break point is hit in p2 at `bar`.

This is based on assumption that `bar` in `p2` will always be hit after `foo` in `p1`.